# How to make sure two standalone ESP32 do not have IP address collide in wifi AP mode?

Tags: arduino, wifi, esp32

I got two simple BOT that run side by side (maybe 40 feet apart) that need to launch a webserver in wifi ap mode. The problem is that the two BOT need to run the exact same software and the first one to power up should choose a predefined IP (like the standard 192.168.4.1) and the next one, the immediate following address (192.168.4.2). So I have look in PainlessMesh but it is overkilled to just make sure the two BOT choose a different IP address base on which come online first.  Project constraint : Both need to run the exact same software.  In case of hardware failure, the ESP32 would be replace with a preprogrammed ESP32. Since there is two bot, the ESP32 replacement module could end up in any of the two BOT. There is no network to connect to. I just need two know if an ESP32 module in wifi ap mode could scan a predefined network to see if there is another ESP32 module using the basic IP address like 192.168.4.1.

I have not lot of experience with the ESP32, and have very short time to come up with a solution.  I have play with PainlessMesh a bit.  I am able to lunch a webserver.  I just need a little nudge in the right direction. Thank you in advance!

Comment: devices in different networks can have the same local IP

Comment: Sorry, do you mean that I could just assign different SSID to each bot?  Like I could read the module manufacturer ID or maybe the mac address dynamically and add it to a prefixed network like MyBots_MAC_address.

Comment: the default ssid of softap is different for every esp32.

Answer (score -1):

My best way to solve this problem is to create DHCP permanent lease in wifi router, one for each ESP, and assign them mac and ip according to the values specified in sketch.

The first start is made in DHCP mode, and ESP IP is randomly set depending on DHCP scope.
by using ping function, I can test if other ESP is present, assign desired mac to ESP, and then write a flag in Eprom.

After first start and flag set, the ESP will no longer change.

each time you install virgin ESP, it will detect other ESP and set second Mac (or first depending wich ip respond), then keep it.

I tested that method and it's working. don't forget to erase flash when programming to be sure eprom is blank.
this is the sketch : change ip and mac values for your requirements.

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiClient.h>
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>
#include <ESP8266mDNS.h>
#include <ESP8266Ping.h>
#include <ESP_EEPROM.h>

#ifndef STASSID
#define STASSID "ssid"
#define STAPSK "password"
#endif

const char *ssid = STASSID;
const char *password = STAPSK;

uint8_t newMACAddress[] = {0x32, 0xAE, 0xA4, 0x07, 0x0D, 0x66};  //32AEA4070D66
uint8_t newMACAddress2[] = {0x32, 0xAE, 0xA4, 0x07, 0x0D, 0x67}; //32AEA4070D67
const IPAddress ip1(192, 168, 4, 1);
const IPAddress ip2(192, 168, 4, 2);
boolean firstStart;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  EEPROM.begin(64);
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);


  uint8_t testVal;
  EEPROM.get(0, testVal);
  Serial.print("eprom read = "); 
  Serial.println(testVal); 
  if ((testVal != 1) && (testVal != 2) ) {
    Serial.println("first start"); //don't set mac
    firstStart = true;
  } else { //subsequent starts
    Serial.println("Eprom allready set");
    firstStart = false;
    if (testVal == 1) {  //set mac depending on eprom read
      // For Soft Access Point (AP) Mode
      //wifi_set_macaddr(SOFTAP_IF, &newMACAddress[0]);
      // For Station Mode
      wifi_set_macaddr(STATION_IF, &newMACAddress[0]);  //set mac 1
    } else wifi_set_macaddr(STATION_IF, &newMACAddress2[0]); //set mac 2
  }
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  Serial.println("");

  // Wait for connection
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    ESP.wdtFeed(); //avoid watchdog reset
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.print("Connected to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);
  Serial.print("IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

  //test connectivity : at first start we get a random ip depending on dhcp scope
  if (firstStart) {
    if (pingIP(ip1)) {   //other ESP present with ip1
      EEPROM.write(0, (uint8_t)2); //set this ESP ip2 next reboot
      if (EEPROM.commit()) Serial.println("Eprom wr 2");
      else Serial.println("Eprom commit fail"); 
    } else if (pingIP(ip2)) {   //other ESP present with ip2
      EEPROM.write(0, (uint8_t)1); //set this ESP ip1 next reboot
      if (EEPROM.commit()) Serial.println("Eprom wr 1");
      else Serial.println("Eprom commit fail"); 
    } else { //no ESP found 
      EEPROM.write(0, (uint8_t)1); //set this ESP ip1 as default
      if (EEPROM.commit()) Serial.println("Eprom wr def 1");
      else Serial.println("Eprom commit fail"); 
    }
    Serial.println("Eprom writed");
    delay(1000);
    ESP.restart();
  }

  if (MDNS.begin("esp8266")) {
    Serial.println("MDNS responder started");
  }
}

void loop() {
  
}

boolean pingIP(IPAddress rIP) {
  Serial.println("try ping..."); 
  if (Ping.ping(rIP, 5)) return true; //Serial.println("ping OK");
  else return false; //Serial.println("ping FAIL");
}
```

If you prefer to deal directly with IP Address, you can adapt sketch to set and store it depending on ping result.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer.  Sorry but per the constraint of the project, their is no wifi router that I could rely on.  Context :  those littles Bots as I call them are part of a circus show that travel all over the world.  Their main function is to display a led string of a certain length base on a position encoder reading.  They are power up on scene and should start displaying the led string right away.  But I also need to be able to do a zero pre-set as a pre show procedure.  Also have the need to OTA the firmware as the ESP module are not easily accessible.

Comment: OK so if in AP mode ESP must first try to connect to other ESP by common SSID and temporary IP, and if succesful test other IP, and finally switch to AP mode with another predefined IP adresse. If connexion unsuccesful, switch to AP mode with default IP. I think it's perfectly achievable. You can use my exemple for implementing it. Don't be afraid to come back for help.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Last night I had a similar idea!  But since both Bots does not really need to talk to each others @Juraj idea is crazy simple.  I will try it and report back on my success!